# How to catch exception without throw

Tags: c++

There is a CRASH in Function() due to some exceptions so, throw X would not be called. In this case how to call catch block to handle exceptions?
**NOTE:** we can't modify the code in Function() definition

**Sample code:**

```
 cout << "Before try \n";
      try {
          abc->Function();  //Here is CRASH

              throw x;
              cout << "After throw (Never executed) \n";

      }
      catch (...) {
          cout << "Exception Caught \n";
      }

      cout << "After catch (Will be executed) \n";
```

So can anyone help me out for this?

Comment: You can *only* `catch` C++ exceptions which were `throw`n.

Comment: You have an extra  `}` bracket after try block..

Comment: On Windows, if you pass the [`/EHa` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx) to the compiler, you can catch access violations (and other Windows SEH exceptions) as C++ exceptions.  But this is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Exceptions only happen for very specific types of errors. If it's not an exception (and it sounds like it's not), you can't catch it. If it's something like a segfault or division by zero, you need to fix the code so it doesn't happen.

Comment: If the row after `catch` is executed (as your question indicates), it would seem that you're getting an exception in `Function` that is caught by the catch and makes your code skip the `throw` line. To help fix that, you need to clarify what you want a little. What is your expected behavior when `Function` indeed throws an exception vs. completes successfully?

Comment: What kind of "CRASH" do you have in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "CRASH" is not an exception. It is [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Absolutely anything could have happened. You are lucky that the system detected it. It could have formatted your disk or summoned daemons out of your nose. Instead the system is only shutting down the process to prevent further damage.

The system *might* even be so kind as to let you define what to do instead of shutting down the process. The way to define it is system specific. In Unix, you need to [install signal handler](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) (the [advanced way](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html)), in Windows you use [structural exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But the problem is that if the function crashed, there is no way to tell how big mess it left the memory of the process in. You really have to fix the crash. A crash is always a bug.

The fact that a crash is inside that function does not automatically mean the bug is in that function. Most crashes I've seen happened in standard library functions, but they were not bugs in standard library. They were caused by incorrect use of those functions, or sometimes incorrect use of something different much earlier in the program. Because when you invoke [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), there's no telling *when* it will cause a crash. Especially buffer overruns and writes to uninitialized pointers tend to cause crashes *eventually* when some unrelated code wants to use the variable that was overwritten.

That said if the bug is indeed in that function and you can't modify it, you will have to get somebody who can or find an alternative that works better. Because there's no way the program is going to work correctly otherwise.

Comment: very nice explanation Jan Hudec. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Bhushan1388: I should add that most common reason for crashes long after the actual bug are buffer overruns and access to invalid but non-null pointers.

Answer (score 1):

There's an aditional '}' in the `try` block in your code. Not sure whether that was an error in typing the code or from another higher level block.

The `catch(...){}` block will be executed when any unhandled exception is thrown inside the `try {}` block. It doesn't matter whether the exceptions are thrown directly under the block or somewhere deep down in other function calls in the block.

```
cout << "Before try \n";
try 
{
    abc->Function1();  //A potential for crash
    abc->Function2();  //Another potential for crash
    abc->Function3();  //Another potential for crash

    // Do some checks and throw an exception.
    throw x;
    cout << "After throw (Never executed) \n";
}
catch (...) 
{
   // This will catch all unhandled exceptions
   // within the try{} block. Those can be from
   // abc->Function1(), abc->Function2(), abc->Function3(),
   // or the throw x within the block itself.
   cout << "Exception Caught \n";
}

cout << "After catch (Will be executed) \n";
```

Hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here us the meaning of try and catch

```
try {
 //[if some ABC type exception occur inside this block,]              
}catch (ABC) {
 //[Then, Do the things inside this block.] 
}
```

So
after the exception occur in your  `abc->Function();` flow will directly jump in to `catch` block so write there what you need to do. as example.

```
try {
  abc->Function();  //Here is CRASH
  throw x;
  cout << "After throw (Never executed) \n";
}catch (Exception ex) {
  cout << "Exception Caught \n";
  throw ex;
}
```

actually `throw x;` doesn't have any use here. because if your `abc->Function();` worked fine, then it will throw an exception. so just remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

the code you have written works exactly true . the compiler when see the throw command every where in the `try{}` it will go to the `catch(){}` so the `cout << "After throw (Never executed) \n";` won't execute and then the code after the `catch(){}` will execute

for reading more about this case here is the link [trycatch](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/)

Answer (score -1):

If you got exception ,

```
abc->Function();  //Here is CRASH
```

You will enter in `catch(...)` block.

If you are using Windows OS, for OS generated exceptions you also need to use `__try/__catch`

Comment: That depends on the nature of the exception. `catch(...)` does not catch everything. You might need to use `__try/__except` to catch SEH exceptions that `catch(...)` misses.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes Windows that's true.. editing my answer.

Comment: Is it possible - catch block is execution without writing throw block in the code?

Comment: -1: A crash is a crash. It is not catchable in C++. It is [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It can be handled in system-specific way, but the program is unlikely to continue working properly after a segmentation fault anyway.

Comment: @Bhushan1388: No, crash can't be caught. On windows it can be with a separate mechanism, on unix it can be handled with different mechanism, but the program is quite likely to misbehave afterwards anyway.